# return string from null on android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem : I use a web service to return some values , but some times some problems face the web services , and when I want to display them my app crashes , so I want to make sure that if there is nothing to show then return just empty space , and I use it on JSON , there is a part of my code if someone can help me ,

```
public static Article parseArticle(JSONObject jsonArticle) {

        Article article = new Article();

        try {
            article.setTitle(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(jsonArticle.getString("title")).toString()));
            article.setExcerpt(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(jsonArticle.getString("excerpt")).toString()));
            article.setContent(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(jsonArticle.getString("content")).toString()));
            article.setDate(jsonArticle.getString("date"));


            return article;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

private void loadinfo() {

         {
            programs = JSONParser.parseProgram(savedData);
            txt1.setText(article.get(1).getTitle());
            txt2.setText(article.get(0).getTitle());
            txt3.setText(article.get(1).excerpt());
            txt4.setText(article.get(0).excerpt());
            txt5.setText(article.get(1).content());
            txt6.setText(article.get(0).content());
            txt7.setText(article.get(1).date());
            txt8.setText(article.get(0).date());
        }
```

this is what happened when i try to have information it give error on

```
        txt1.setText(article.get(1).getTitle());
```

that there is no values

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); what does it return ?

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood you instead of `jsonArticle.getString` you can use `jsonArticle.optString`. It will return an empty `String` if the json does not contain that key.

```
String mString = jsonArticle.optString("title");
article.setTitle(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
mString = jsonArticle.optString("excerpt");                 
article.setExcerpt(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
mString = jsonArticle.optString("content");                     
article.setContent(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
mString = jsonArticle.optString("date");             
article.setDate(mString);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29) the doc for `optString()`

EDIT

```
public static Article parseArticle(JSONObject jsonArticle) {

    Article article = new Article();

    try {
            String mString = jsonArticle.optString("title");
            article.setTitle(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
            mString = jsonArticle.optString("excerpt");                 
            article.setExcerpt(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
            mString = jsonArticle.optString("content");                     
            article.setContent(ArabicUtilities.reshape(Html.fromHtml(mString).toString()));
            mString = jsonArticle.optString("date");             
            article.setDate(mString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

       return article;
}
```

Comment: what you mean by optString ? how i can use it ? im just beginner so that's why sorry

Comment: can you post your Article class?

Comment: in loadInfo article what type is ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Article parseArticle(JSONObject jsonArticle) {
     Article article = new Article();
    if(null!=jsonArticle){
        try {
            /*your code */
    }else{
        article.setTitle(ArabicUtilities.reshape("");
        article.setExcerpt(ArabicUtilities.reshape("");
        article.setContent(ArabicUtilities.reshape("");
        article.setDate("");
        return article;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes that what i want but i don't know how to make date , title ... to  null and not show any msg